# HPE mobile center server configuration

Tags: hp-uft, microfocus-mobile-center

I need to install the HPE Mobile Center Connector on my local pc without any server just for a trial with UFT. can anyone advice what should i give in the Mobile center IP Address? since server port is by default: 8080

Comment: Tried `localhost`?

Comment: yes i did provide the local host ip 127.0.0.1 but it is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test mobile with UFT you need to have a mobile center server installed.

The Mobile Center Connector is not used by UFT, it's just a way to connect mobile devices to the MC server without physically connecting the device to the server machine. You should think of the *connector* as a way to extend the MC server. UFT connects to the server and can see all devices connected to the server (either physically or via *connector*) so if you don't have a server machine the *connector* has no meaning.

You can install the MC sever on a virtual machine if this helps.

Comment: is there anyway to run the MC on my local pc ? only for a testing purpose since i already installed the MC but whenever i set the mobile server setting here is the problem

Comment: @compiler AFAIK MC is only supported on linux (I may be wrong) in which case you can install it on a virtual machine on your local pc but not directly on the windows pc.

Answer (score 0):

You can install MC all in one which includes server + connector. It's supported for both Windows & Linux.
There is a trial version so you can test it with UFT.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try out Mobile testing with UFT, there is a free resource that you can use:
https://marketplace.microfocus.com/appdelivery/content/uft-mobile-add-in-for-local-device

More info from Micro Focus marketplace:

"This “add-in” acts as a connector between UFT and the mobile devices connected directly to the UFT machine. In just a few steps, UFT users can start designing and running mobile app and web tests on one local mobile device at a time without purchasing an additional license. Whether you work in Retail, Telecom, Finance, or other adjacent industries, the UFT Mobile Add-in for Local Devices is a great fit for testers who need to:

- Execute their omnichannel content strategy using the same script for desktop and mobile web content
- Support mobile testing in organisations that do not have a lab management solution in place
- Run mobile tests without needing a new tool for mobile only"